# Remove directory level when transferring from HDFS to S3 using S3DistCp

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, apache-pig, hdfs, emr

I have a Pig script (using a slightly modified [MultiStorage](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/MultiStorage.html)) that transforms some data. Once the script runs, I have data in the following format on HDFS:

```
/tmp/data/identifier1/indentifier1-0,0001  
/tmp/data/identifier1/indentifier1-0,0002  
/tmp/data/identifier2/indentifier2-0,0001  
/tmp/data/identifier3/indentifier3-0,0001
```

I'm attempting to use S3DistCp to copy these files to S3. I am using the `--groupBy .*(identifier[0-9]).*` option to combine files based on the identifier. The combination works, but when copying to S3, the folders are also copied. The end output is:

```
/s3bucket/identifier1/identifier1
/s3bucket/identifier2/identifier2
/s3bucket/identifier3/identifier3
```

Is there a way to copy these files without that first folder? Ideally, my output in S3 would look like:

```
/s3bucket/identifier1
/s3bucket/identifier2
/s3bucket/identifier3
```

Another solution I've considered is to use HDFS commands to pull those files out of their directories before copying to S3. Is that a reasonable solution?

Thanks!

Comment: can you post your command.

Comment: Assuming you mean by s3distcp command, here are the arguments passed to the EMR step: `--s3Endpoint s3.amazonaws.com --src hdfs:///tmp/data/ --dest s3://output --groupBy .*/(identifier).*`

Comment: At this point in time s3distcp cannot flatten the directories.  Way in on https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=479023&#479023 for feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution I've arrived upon is to use `distcp` to bring these files out of the directories before using `s3distcp`:

```
hadoop distcp -update /tmp/data/** /tmp/grouped
```

Then, I changed the `s3distcp` script to move data from `/tmp/grouped` into my S3 bucket.

Comment: I tried this solution but the copy errored with the complaint that it `would cause duplicates.`. This is because I had files with the same name in different subdirectories. Is there an easy way to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `distcp` before `s3distcp` is really expensive. One other option you have is to create a manifest file with all your files in it and give its path to `s3distcp`. In this manifest you can define the "base name" of each file. If you need an example of a manifest file just run `s3distcp` on any folder with argument `--outputManifest`.
more information can be found [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_s3distcp.html)